# Is it possible to execute CMD at the middle of docker file?

Tags: hadoop, docker, boot2docker, dockerfile

I am installing hadoop-0.20.2 using docker. I have two files one is for java installation and another is for hadoop installation. I am starting services using CMD command

```
 cmd ["path/to/start-all.sh"]
```

Now, i want to to write third dockerfile which executes an example Map-Reduce job. But the problem is

Third docker file depends on second hadoop-docker file. fo eg:

```
 FROM sec_doc_file

 RUN /bin/hadoop fs -mkdir input
```

It requires hadoop services. But hadoop services ll be started only after running second docker file. But i want to run it as part of third docker file before starting MR job? Is it possible? If so, please provide an example. If not, what could be the other possibilities?

```
 #something like

 From sec_doc_file

 #Start_Service

 RUN /bin/hadoop fs -mkdir input

 #continue_map_reduce_job
```

Answer (score 1):

The docker image you use as base for the new container is a base for files, not for processes supposed to be running. To do what you want you would need to start the process(es) you need during dockerbuild and run the commands to set up properly. Each `RUN` creates a new AUFS layer, but does not keep the possible previous running services. So, if you need a service to be up to perform some setup during `docker build` you would need to run it in one line (concatenating commands or with a custom script). Example:

```
FROM Gops/sec_doc_file
RUN path/to/start-all.sh && /bin/hadoop fs -mkdir input
```

So for setting up HDFS folders and files during docker build you'd need to run the hdfs daemons and perform the action you wish in the same `RUN` command:

```
RUN /etc/hadoop/hadoop-env.sh &&\
    /opt/hadoop/sbin/start-dfs.sh &&\
    /opt/hadoop/bin/hdfs dfs -mkdir input
```

Comment: So I cannot seperate it into two docker files? what if i have to add n number of lines for map-reduce job?

Comment: You can separate it in the dockerfiles you wish, but each time you run a command that requires a service to be running for other command to work, you need to run than command in the same line. The changes you do (i.e.: creating files in HDFS) will be saved between layers and dockerfiles, but the daemons won't be running between them. About the MR job, is it supposed to be run during docker build?